# Compile the first example of ScaLapack

Tags: makefile, scalapack

I am trying to compile the first example of ScaLapack.
For that I am using a makefile to compile and I am having these error's message:

[image]

I already did all the procedures to install ScaLapack but I think that I have to do some modification in my Makefile in order to compile the example. To compile the program using the makefile just type "make" on the terminal.

Here my makefile and the ScaLapack example:

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/udxk1q6wt0ytzsp/AABwbY99oIUy9a2n9VPx90hxa?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a couple link libraries missing:

`-lscalapack -lblacsF77 -lblacs` is good place to start. Let me know, if you still have issues.